# Integrated weblogic server is not running

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

while starting integrated weblogic server I am getting following error in v11.1.1.7.0

> User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated.
>   **** Authentication error while connecting to application server IntegratedWebLogicServer. Please check settings.
>   **** Failed to complete start-up of application server IntegratedWebLogicServer. [Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer is
>   shutting down.  All applications currently running will be terminated
>   and undeployed.] [Forcing termination of IntegratedWebLogicServer]
>   taskkill /F /PID 6448 Process exited.

any suggestion that might help?

Comment: Did you install something? Did you check the settings?

Comment: no i didn't install anything...but I accidentally deleted Integratedweblogic server in application server pallet but it again appeared but while I am trying to run it it is showing the above error....is there any chance to re configure the server?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the defaultDomain directory in JDeveloper's USER system directory.
Then restart JDeveloper. Also make sure you are using the correct JDK version and that your JDeveloper is not installed in a directory that contains a path in it.